(NOBRIDGE) ERROR Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either
I am working on a gaming app and this seems to bother me for a very long time. I tried different approaches but none of them seem to work. I hope someone will help me in solving this maximum update depth issue. This is coming when I running a stress test on the handleLikeLoadout function.
 (NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
What changes do I need to make so this error will. not bother me anymore? This is the code that I am executing:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Share
} from "react-native";
import { TabView, TabBar } from "react-native-tab-view";
import Banner from "./Banner";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5";
import WZLoadouts from "./WZLoadouts";
import WZFavouriteLoadouts from "./WZFavouriteLoadouts";
import WZMyLoadouts from "./WZMyLoadouts";
import WZCreateLoadout from "./WZCreateLoadout";
import { getDatabase, ref, get, push, update, set, onValue, remove } from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import fetchAllUsers from '../assets/data/retrieveData'
import { isEqual as deepEqual } from "lodash";


const CodComponent = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [list, setList] = useState({});
  const [user, setUser] = useState({userLoad: [], userFav: [] });
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({});
  const [userFav, setUserFav] = useState([]); // Initialize as an array
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const auth = useMemo(() => getAuth(), []);
  const db = useMemo(() => getDatabase(), []);
  
  const initialLayout = { width: Dimensions.get("window").width };
  const backgroundImage = require("../assets/images/v197_60.png");


  const weaponAttachments = {
    AK41: {
      Optic: ["3x Optic", "Holo Optic", "Red Dot Sight", "Thermal Scope", "Viper Reflex Sight"],
      Muzzle: ["Muzzle 1", "Muzzle 2", "Flash Hider", "Suppressor", "Compensator", "Monolithic Suppressor"],
      Stock: ["Stock 1", "Stock 2", "Collapsed Stock", "Tactical Stock", "Pro Stock"],
      Barrel: ["Barrel 1", "Barrel 2", "Long Barrel", "Heavy Barrel", "Short Barrel", "Precision Barrel"],
      Underbarrel: ["Vertical Grip", "Angled Grip", "Bipod", "Commander Grip"],
      RearGrip: ["Rubber Grip", "Taped Grip", "Granulated Grip", "Speed Grip"],
      Ammunition: ["Extended Mag", "Fast Mags", "FMJ Rounds", "High Velocity Rounds", "Drum Mag"],
      Laser: ["Laser Sight", "Infrared Laser", "Tactical Laser"],
      Perk: ["FMJ", "Fully Loaded", "Recon", "Sleight of Hand", "Ghost"],
    },    
    M4A1: {
      Optic: ["3x Optic", "Holo Optic", "Red Dot Sight", "Thermal Scope", "Viper Reflex Sight"],
      Muzzle: ["Muzzle 1", "Muzzle 2", "Flash Hider", "Suppressor", "Compensator", "Monolithic Suppressor"],
      Stock: ["Stock 1", "Stock 2", "Collapsed Stock", "Tactical Stock", "Pro Stock"],
      Barrel: ["Barrel 1", "Barrel 2", "Long Barrel", "Heavy Barrel", "Short Barrel", "Precision Barrel"],
      Underbarrel: ["Vertical Grip", "Angled Grip", "Bipod", "Commander Grip"],
      RearGrip: ["Rubber Grip", "Taped Grip", "Granulated Grip", "Speed Grip"],
      Ammunition: ["Extended Mag", "Fast Mags", "FMJ Rounds", "High Velocity Rounds", "Drum Mag"],
      Laser: ["Laser Sight", "Infrared Laser", "Tactical Laser"],
      Perk: ["FMJ", "Fully Loaded", "Recon", "Sleight of Hand", "Ghost"],
    },
    BullFrog: {
      Optic: ["3x Optic", "Holo Optic", "Red Dot Sight", "Thermal Scope", "Viper Reflex Sight"],
      Muzzle: ["Muzzle 1", "Muzzle 2", "Flash Hider", "Suppressor", "Compensator", "Monolithic Suppressor"],
      Stock: ["Stock 1", "Stock 2", "Collapsed Stock", "Tactical Stock", "Pro Stock"],
      Barrel: ["Barrel 1", "Barrel 2", "Long Barrel", "Heavy Barrel", "Short Barrel", "Precision Barrel"],
      Underbarrel: ["Vertical Grip", "Angled Grip", "Bipod", "Commander Grip"],
      RearGrip: ["Rubber Grip", "Taped Grip", "Granulated Grip", "Speed Grip"],
      Ammunition: ["Extended Mag", "Fast Mags", "FMJ Rounds", "High Velocity Rounds", "Drum Mag"],
      Laser: ["Laser Sight", "Infrared Laser", "Tactical Laser"],
      Perk: ["FMJ", "Fully Loaded", "Recon", "Sleight of Hand", "Ghost"],
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const codRef = ref(db, "COD");
    const codListener = onValue(codRef, (snapshot) => {
      const loadouts = snapshot.exists() ? snapshot.val() : {};
      const sortedLoadouts = Object.values(loadouts)
        .sort((a, b) => (b.likes?.length || 0) - (a.likes?.length || 0))
        .reduce((acc, loadout) => {
          acc[loadout.id] = loadout;
          return acc;
        }, {});
  
      setList((prevList) => {
        const prevLoadouts = Object.values(prevList);
        const sortedPrevLoadouts = prevLoadouts
          .sort((a, b) => (b.likes?.length || 0) - (a.likes?.length || 0));
        
        if (JSON.stringify(sortedPrevLoadouts) !== JSON.stringify(Object.values(sortedLoadouts))) {
          return sortedLoadouts;
        }
        return prevList;
      });
    });
  
    let userListener;
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if (user) {
      const userRef = ref(db, `users/${user.uid}`);
      userListener = onValue(userRef, (snapshot) => {
        const userData = snapshot.exists()
          ? snapshot.val()
          : { userFav: [], userLoad: [] };
  
        setUser((prevUser) => {
          if (!deepEqual(prevUser, userData)) {
            return userData;
          }
          return prevUser;
        });
  
        setUserFav((prevFav) => {
          if (!deepEqual(prevFav, userData.userFav)) {
            return userData.userFav;
          }
          return prevFav;
        });
      });
    }
  
    return () => {
      codListener();
      if (userListener) userListener();
    };
  }, [db, auth]);
  
  
  const fetchMoreLoadouts = async () => {
    const codRef = ref(db, "COD");
    const snapshot = await get(codRef);
    const allLoadouts = snapshot.exists() ? snapshot.val() : {};
  
    const currentLoadouts = Object.keys(list); // IDs of loadouts already displayed
    const remainingLoadouts = Object.values(allLoadouts)
      .filter((loadout) => !currentLoadouts.includes(loadout.id)) // Exclude already loaded items
      .sort((a, b) => (b.likes?.length || 0) - (a.likes?.length || 0)); // Sort remaining loadouts
  
    return remainingLoadouts.slice(0, 10); // Fetch the next 10 loadouts
  };
  
  const loadMoreLoadouts = async () => {
    const newLoadouts = await fetchMoreLoadouts();
  
    setList((prevList) => {
      const mergedList = { ...prevList };
  
      // Add new loadouts and re-sort the entire list
      newLoadouts.forEach((loadout) => {
        mergedList[loadout.id] = loadout;
      });
  
      return Object.values(mergedList)
        .sort((a, b) => (b.likes?.length || 0) - (a.likes?.length || 0)) // Re-sort by likes
        .reduce((acc, loadout) => {
          acc[loadout.id] = loadout;
          return acc;
        }, {});
    });
  };

  const handleDeleteLoadout = (loadout) => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Delete Loadout",
      "Are you sure you want to delete this loadout?",
      [
        { text: "Cancel", style: "cancel" },
        {
          text: "Delete",
          style: "destructive",
          onPress: async () => {
            try {
              const loadoutRef = ref(db, `COD/${loadout.id}`); // Reference to the loadout data
              const userLoadRef = ref(db, `users/${loadout.userId}/userLoad`); // Reference to the user's loadout array
              const usersRef = ref(db, "users"); // Reference to all users for additional cleanup if needed
  
              // Fetch the user's userLoad array
              const userSnapshot = await get(userLoadRef);
              if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
                const userLoadArray = userSnapshot.val(); // Firebase array format
                const updatedUserLoad = userLoadArray.filter((id) => id !== loadout.id);
  
                // Update the user's loadout array
                await update(ref(db, `users/${loadout.userId}`), { userLoad: updatedUserLoad });
              }
  
              // Remove the loadout from the COD collection
              await remove(loadoutRef);
  
              // Clean up any additional userFav references if applicable
              const usersSnapshot = await get(usersRef);
              if (usersSnapshot.exists()) {
                const usersData = usersSnapshot.val();
                const updates = {};
  
                // Remove the loadout from all userFav arrays
                Object.entries(usersData).forEach(([userId, userData]) => {
                  if (userData.userFav && userData.userFav.includes(loadout.id)) {
                    updates[`users/${userId}/userFav`] = userData.userFav.filter(
                      (favId) => favId !== loadout.id
                    );
                  }
                });
  
                if (Object.keys(updates).length > 0) {
                  await update(ref(db), updates); // Apply all updates at once
                }
              }
  
              // Update local state
              setList((prevList) => {
                const updatedList = { ...prevList };
                delete updatedList[loadout.id];
                return updatedList;
              });
  
              setUser((prevUser) => ({
                ...prevUser,
                userLoad: prevUser.userLoad?.filter((id) => id !== loadout.id),
              }));
  
              Alert.alert("Success", "Loadout deleted successfully.");
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error deleting loadout:", error);
              Alert.alert("Error", "Could not delete loadout: " + error.message);
            }
          },
        },
      ]
    );
  };
  
  // Handle sharing a loadout
  const handleShareLoadout = async (loadout) => {
    try {
      // Construct the unique URL with the app-specific scheme and loadout ID
      const loadoutUrl = `coleeApp://expo-development-client/cod`;
      console.log(loadout.gun.attachments)
      // Ensure attachments is an array or use a fallback
      const attachmentsList = Array.isArray(loadout.gun.attachments)
      ? loadout.gun.attachments.join(", ") // Join array elements as a string
      : loadout.gun.attachments && typeof loadout.gun.attachments === 'object'
      ? Object.values(loadout.gun.attachments).join(", ") // Join object values if attachments is an object
      : "No attachments"; // Fallback when attachments is neither an array nor an object
    
  
      // Share the message with detailed loadout information
      const shareOptions = {
        message: `Check out this loadout:\n` +
                 `Title: ${loadout.title.name}\n` +
                 `Range: ${loadout.title.range}\n` +
                 `Type: ${loadout.title.type}\n` +
                 `Game: ${loadout.title.game}\n\n` +
                 `Gun: ${loadout.gun.name}\n` +
                 `Attachments: ${attachmentsList}\n\n` +
                 `Open in the app: ${loadoutUrl}`,
      };
  
      await Share.share(shareOptions);
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("Error", `Could not share the loadout: ${error.message}`);
    }
  };
  
  
  


  const createLoadout = async (
    title,
    weapon,
    range,
    game,
    weaponType,
    attachments,
    uid
  ) => {
    // console.log(attachments);
    try {
      // Check if the user is authenticated
      if (!uid) {
        throw new Error("User is not authenticated");
      }
  
      // Save to `COD` root object in Firebase
      const codRef = ref(db, "COD");
      const newLoadoutRef = push(codRef);
  
      // Get the generated ID of the loadout
      const loadoutId = newLoadoutRef.key;
  
      // Prepare the new loadout object with loadoutId
      const newLoadout = {
        id: loadoutId, // Add the loadoutId here
        title: { name: title, range, type: weaponType, game },
        gun: { name: weapon, attachments },
        userId: uid,
        likes: [],
        updatedAt: new Date().toISOString(),
      };
  
      // Save the loadout to Firebase
      await update(newLoadoutRef, newLoadout);
  
      // Update the user's `userLoad` array in Firebase
      const userRef = ref(db, `users/${uid}`);
      const userSnapshot = await get(userRef); // Fetch current user data
  
      if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
        const userData = userSnapshot.val();
        const updatedUserLoad = [...(userData.userLoad || []), loadoutId];
  
        await update(userRef, {
          userLoad: updatedUserLoad,
        });
      } else {
        // Handle the case where the user object doesn't exist
        await set(userRef, { userLoad: [loadoutId] });
      }
  
      // Update the list in the state
      setList((prevList) => {
        const updatedList = { ...prevList, [newLoadout.id]: newLoadout };
        return Object.values(updatedList)
          .sort((a, b) => (b.likes?.length || 0) - (a.likes?.length || 0))
          .slice(0, 10)
          .reduce((acc, loadout) => {
            acc[loadout.id] = loadout;
            return acc;
          }, {});
      });
  
      Alert.alert("Success", "Loadout successfully created.");
      // console.log("Loadout successfully created and saved to Firebase.");
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any errors (including authentication errors)
      console.error("Error creating loadout:", error);
      Alert.alert(
        "Error",
        error.message || "An error occurred while creating the loadout."
      );
    }
  };
  
  
  const handleLikeLoadout = async (loadout) => {
    try {
      // Check if the user is authenticated
      const user = auth.currentUser;
      if (!user) {
        Alert.alert(
          "Authentication Required",
          "Please log in to like or unlike posts. This helps us ensure a personalized experience for you.",
          [{ text: "Cancel", style: "cancel" }],
          { cancelable: true }
        );
        return;
      }
  
      const userId = user.uid;
      const currentLikes = loadout.likes || []; // Ensure likes is an array
      const isLiked = currentLikes.includes(userId);
  
      // Toggle the like status for the loadout
      const updatedLikes = isLiked
        ? currentLikes.filter((uid) => uid !== userId) // Remove user's like
        : [...currentLikes, userId]; // Add user's like
  
      const loadoutRef = ref(db, `COD/${loadout.id}`);
      await update(loadoutRef, { likes: updatedLikes });
  
      // Fetch and update the user's favorites
      const userRef = ref(db, `users/${userId}`);
      const userSnapshot = await get(userRef);
      const userData = userSnapshot.exists()
        ? userSnapshot.val()
        : { userFav: [] }; // Default to an object with empty userFav array
  
      const updatedUserFav = isLiked
        ? (userData.userFav || []).filter((favId) => favId !== loadout.id) // Ensure array before filter
        : [...(userData.userFav || []), loadout.id]; // Add loadout ID to favorites
  
      await update(userRef, { userFav: updatedUserFav });
  
      // Update the local state
      setList((prevList) => ({
        ...prevList,
        [loadout.id]: { ...prevList[loadout.id], likes: updatedLikes },
      }));
  
      setUserFav(updatedUserFav); // Reflect the updated favorite list in the state
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating like/favorite:", error);
      Alert.alert(
        "Error",
        "An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later."
      );
    }
  };
  
  

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsAdmin(user?.title === "Admin" || false);
  }, [user]);
  

  const renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
      case "first":
        return <WZLoadouts list={list} userFav={userFav} users={users} handleLikeLoadout={handleLikeLoadout} handleDeleteLoadout={handleDeleteLoadout} handleShareLoadout={handleShareLoadout} isAdmin={isAdmin} loadMoreLoadouts={loadMoreLoadouts}/>;
      // case "second":
      //   return (
      //     <WZFavouriteLoadouts
      //       list={Object.values(list).filter((_, index) =>
      //         userFav.includes(_[0].id) // Filter by favorites
      //       )}
      //     />
      //   );
      // case "third":
      //   return (
      //     <WZMyLoadouts
      //       list={Object.values(list).filter((_, index) =>
      //         user.userLoad.includes(_[0].id)
      //       )}
      //       userFav={userFav}
      //     />
      //   );
      case "fourth":
        return (
          <WZCreateLoadout
            createLoadout={createLoadout}
            weaponAttachments={weaponAttachments}
          />
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  const renderLabel = ({ route }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
        {route.key === "first" && <Icon name="list" size={20} color="white" />}
        {route.key === "second" && <Icon name="heart" size={20} color="white" />}
        {route.key === "third" && <Icon name="user" size={20} color="white" />}
        {route.key === "fourth" && <Icon name="plus" size={20} color="white" />}
      </View>
    );
  };

  const [routes] = useState([
    { key: "first" },
    { key: "second" },
    { key: "third" },
    { key: "fourth" },
  ]);

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={backgroundImage}
      style={styles.backgroundImage}
      resizeMode="cover"
      blurRadius={3}
    >
      <Banner />
      <View style={styles.pageContentContainer}>
        <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
          <TabView
            navigationState={{ index, routes }}
            renderScene={renderScene}
            onIndexChange={setIndex}
            initialLayout={initialLayout}
            renderTabBar={(props) => (
              <LinearGradient
                colors={[
                  "rgba(128,183,74,1)",
                  "rgba(91,119,63,1)",
                  "rgba(58,62,54,1)",
                  "rgba(52,52,52,1)",
                ]}
                style={styles.tabBar}
              >
                {props.navigationState.routes.map((route, idx) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    key={route.key}
                    style={styles.tabItem}
                    onPress={() => setIndex(idx)} // Handle tab switching
                  >
                    {renderLabel({ route })}
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ))}
              </LinearGradient>
            )}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
  pageContentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 105, // Adjust this value based on banner height
  },
  tabContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 25,
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  tabBar: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderRadius: 10,
    overflow: "hidden",
  },
  tabItem: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  tabBarTransparent: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    shadowColor: "transparent",
  },
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  tabLabel: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 12, // Adjust font size to fit in one line
  },
  labelContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default CodComponent;



I tried all the solutions present in any other opened issues

It looks like one of you have an useEffect that is being called a lot. From what I saw you have two of them: one that depends on db and auth; and another that depends on user. The db/auth is memoized so I don’t think its the problem; which leaves the user one

How often are you calling setUser?

@PhantomSpooks It is a stress test so it was like 10 times per second but I added a 0 delay in executing it and it seems to work so the users will not be able to spam the button and flood the database with requests.
  useEffect(() => {
    let timeoutId;
    const codRef = ref(db, "COD");
    const codListener = onValue(codRef, (snapshot) => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        const loadouts = snapshot.exists() ? snapshot.val() : {};
        const sortedLoadouts = Object.values(loadouts)
        .sort((a, b) => (b.likes?.length || 0) - (a.likes?.length || 0))
        .reduce((acc, loadout) => {
          acc[loadout.id] = loadout;
          return acc;
        }, {});
        setList(sortedLoadouts);
      }, 0); // Debounce for 0ms
    });
  
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      codListener();
    };
  }, [db]);

